# how do i set coordinates of point? JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jsxgraph

I am unable to change coordinates of point dynamically. Trying to create a vector calculation but not able to set coordinates point to element.

```
a = board.create('point', [1, 1], {name: 'A',color:'green',size: .5,withLabel:false}),
board.create('arrow', [[0,0], a], {color:'green'});

b = board.create('point', [-1, 1], {name: 'B',color:'red',size: .5,withLabel:false}),
board.create('arrow', [[0,0], b], {color:'red'});

let xr = a.X() + b.X();
let yr = a.Y() + b.Y();
r = board.create('point', [xr, yr], {name: 'R',color:'black',size: .5,withLabel:false}),
board.create('arrow', [[0,0], r], {color:'black'});

board.on('update', function(){
    let xr = a.X() + b.X();
    let yr = a.Y() + b.Y();
    r.point2.setPosition([xr,yr]);
    board.fullUpdate();
});
```

setPosition is not working. I want to set the updated value of xr and xy everytime update event is called.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most "JSXGraphy" way to realize your example would be to define the coordinates of the point `r` to be functions.

```
var a = board.create('point', [1, 1], {
            name: 'A', color:'green', size: .5, withLabel:false
        }),
    b = board.create('point', [-1, 1], {
            name: 'B', color:'red', size: .5, withLabel:false
        }),
    r = board.create('point', [
            function() { return a.X() + b.X(); },
            function() { return a.Y() + b.Y(); }], {
            name: 'R', color:'black', size: .5, withLabel:false
        });

board.create('arrow', [[0,0], a], {color:'green'});
board.create('arrow', [[0,0], b], {color:'red'});
board.create('arrow', [[0,0], r], {color:'black'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve using

```
r.point2.setPositionDirectly(JXG.COORDS_BY_USER,[xr,yr])
```

note that this will only work after board is updated.

```
board.update();
```

Above solution is more faster than using moveTo.